# How do I display variables passed from Express in an Angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable that I passed from Express initially to a page which also uses AngularJS. However when I try to access it with {{}}, it doesn't seem to appear. Does this only retrieve variables from the $scope? If so, how do I display other variables in AngularJS?

Comment: Yes, the HTML get variables from `$scope`, you need to assign object to `$scope.*` to make it usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define values or constants.
For example, put following code in before `</body>`.

```
<script>
angular.module('your-module').constant('foo', 'bar');
angular.module('your-module').value('obj', {some: 1, encoded: {obj: 'xx'}});
</script>
```

Then you can inject `foo` and `obj` in your controllers/services respectively.